# Disable scroll zoom in Bing Maps v8

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I need to disable zooming by scroll in Bing Maps API v8, but keep the zooming buttons.

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(mapPlaceholderElement,
{
    credentials: options.credentials,
    disableZooming: true, //If this is true, the showZoomButtons is not applied
    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
    navigationBarMode: Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode.compact,
    showZoomButtons: true
});
```

Is there any way, how to enable the buttons and disable the zoom scrolling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was just added to the experimental branch of the V8 control last week. To use this you first need to add "&branch=experimental" to the map script URL. You can then add `disableScrollWheelZoom: true` as a map option. This will be merged into the main release branch near the end of the month.

Comment: any idea how one can set the maximum and minimum zoom levels with `v8`?

Comment: Use the minZoom and maxZoom map options. http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#setMaxMinZoom+JS

Answer (score 2):

This is no longer experimental; It is released, and documented.

```
disableScrollWheelZoom: true
```

See the docs here: [MapOptions Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-api/mapoptions-object)